# AVAudioEngine Microphone Crash on Start

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I'm trying to set up an AudioQueue to stream audio from the microphone on an iPhone.

I create my audio engine:

```
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
```

And my audio queue:

```
    // Serial dispatch queue used to analyze incoming audio buffers.
    let analysisQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.apple.AnalysisQueue")


    // Install an audio tap on the audio engine's input node.
    audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0,
                                     bufferSize: 8192, // 8k buffer
                                     format: inputFormat) { buffer, time in

        // Analyze the current audio buffer.
        analysisQueue.async {
        }
    }
```

Whenever I run the code on the simulator or the device, I get the following crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: inputNode != nullptr || outputNode != nullptr'
```

I was following some Apple sample code while making this; somewhat confused. Any help appreciated!

*EDIT*: this question from a few days ago seems to point to a similar issue: [AVAudioEngine.connect crash on hardware not simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486139/avaudioengine-connect-crash-on-hardware-not-simulator)

Comment: First result in Google for `required condition is false: inputNode != nullptr || outputNode != nullptr`: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow missed this thread while googling; but thanks to @SOreadytohelp I got it working -- just add

```
audioEngine.mainMixerNode
```

right above

```
do {
    // Start the stream of audio data.
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    print("Unable to start AVAudioEngine: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: HI @narner, just call the above line of code and do nothing? If that, it will show warning `Expression of type 'AVAudioMixerNode' is unused`.

Comment: It is just warning... put this to unused constant like this: `let _ = audioEngine.mainMixerNode`